# PHP - High order function to map object property to an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm adding an object's **property** into an `array` using a `foreach` statement but I think the code can be made more readable by using a high order function. I'm thinking maybe `array_map` might work but I haven't found how to.

```
$deviceCollection = [];
foreach ($android as $token) {
    $deviceCollection[] = $this->pushNotification->Device($token->token, ['badge' => 1]);
}
```

Can this be done with `array_map` or am I looking at the wrong function?

Answer (score 3):

Can be done, e.g. via

```
$afn = Closure::bind(
    function($token) {
        $this->pushNotification->Device($token->token, ['badge' => 1]);
    },
    $this
);

$deviceCollection = array_map($afn, $android);
```

if `$afn` is used in only one place, I'd say readability is in the eye of the beholder....